# Conversion to non-scalar type with std c++11 smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, openscenegraph

I am currently playing around with openscenegraph and it uses its own smart pointer. But I want to use the std c++11 smart pointer.

now this is the working example code

```
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Uniform> SineUniform   =  new osg::Uniform( "Sine", 0.0f );
```

but when I do something like this

```
std::unique_ptr<osg::Uniform> SineUniform   =  new osg::Uniform( "Sine", 0.0f );
```

Then I get the following error message

> error: conversion from 'osg::Uniform*' to non-scalar type
>   'std::unique_ptr' requested

Any idea what is going on? Are there some requirements for smart pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<osg::Uniform> SineUniform(new osg::Uniform( "Sine", 0.0f ));
```

Also, be careful not to mix different types of smart pointers. OpenSceneGraph may make assumptions on how its objects are managed, and may require using `osg::ref_ptr` instead. You should go through the documentation to find this out - I cannot help with that unfortunately.

Comment: okay thanks you are right, I probably have to use the osg smart pointer.