# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer error using opencv cv::Ptr

Tags: c++, opencv, memory

I'm writing my first opencv code(and first C++ code actually), and met with a strange `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer` error when I try to use cv::Ptr. I see in other posts that this usually results from freeing a already freed area, but I think I didn't.

The following simple testing function will generate that error.

```
void testing(void) {
    int i=2;
    Ptr< Mat > pointer=new Mat[i];
}
```

From the debugger, it seems that the destructor triggers the error when the function returns.I couldn't figure out why since basically I did nothing with the Ptr. So why this is happening and what's the correct usage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do **not** use any kind of pointers with cv::Mat. it already is a smartpointer on its own. pass references or even copies instead.

Comment: I don't intend to pass the the pointer to a function. Rather, I want an array of `cv::Mat` of the same length as channel numbers so that I can split and deal with them separately. Since I don't know how many channels an image has beforehand, I have to allocate the array like that. Maybe I should use `std::vector<cv::Mat>` instead, but I'm not sure whether I can pass an `std::vector` to `void merge(const Mat* mv, size_t count, OutputArray dst)` as the first parameter.

Comment: please try either a plain `Mat[3]` or a `vector<Mat>` with [this merge overload](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga61f2f2bde4a0a0154b2333ea504fab1d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ there is a significant difference between memory allocated with `new` and memory allocated with `new []`.

```
int* p = new int;
delete p;
p = new int[8];
delete p; // error/crash
delete [] p; // correct
```

The Ptr class is an RAII container for managing ownership of pointers. When you assign to it, it takes ownership of that allocation, meaning it will `delete` it when the Ptr goes out of scope (in this case at the end of the function).

It uses `delete` by default hence your crash, and the documentation suggests you will need to use the constructor that lets you specify you own deleter:

```
// see http://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/de7/structcv_1_1Ptr.html
void array_deleter(Mat* m)
{
    delete [] m;
}

Prt<Mat> ptr(new Mat[i], array_deleter);
```

Comment: So does that mean whatever object `cv::Ptr` owns, the destructor will default to `DefaultDeleter`,which is actually a standard C++ `delete`? Also, why I can use `unique_ptr<int[]> = new int[i]` but get `error: conversion from ‘cv::Mat*’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Ptr<cv::Mat []>’ requested` when I try `Ptr< Mat[] > ptr=new Mat[i]`. What's the difference? Is it because the conversion from `int*` to `int[]` is somehow defined, but `cv::Mat*` to `cv::Mat[]` is not?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364637/conversion-to-non-scalar-type-with-std-c11-smart-pointer and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique if you have c++14

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. For those confused about the difference between `std::unique_ptr<osg::Uniform> SineUniform   =  new osg::Uniform( "Sine", 0.0f );`  and  `std::unique_ptr<osg::Uniform> SineUniform(new osg::Uniform( "Sine", 0.0f ));` from the link kfsone provided as I did, I've found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081743/for-a-class-constructor-what-is-the-difference-between-the-assignment-via-paren